# Are game development resource recommendations on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Game recommendation questions [are off-topic](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/3389). However, card recommendation questions for a specific game [are on-topic](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1719/3389).

Are game development resource recommendations on-topic? For instance, [Where to go to self publish a game?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/13553/3389) recently got bumped to the main page. It's not a game recommendation, so it's not off-topic for that reason, but it does have a number of similarities to it.

Would this type of question be on-topic? And if so, what is an appropriate close reason?

Comment: Whoops, I voted to close as a duplicate of the wrong question, and now I can't recast my vote. In any case, I think this is a duplicate of [Why are game recommendation questions off-topic?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6692), because I don't see why any of that reasoning wouldn't apply here. Card recommendations are the exception to the rule in my opinion.

Comment: @Rainbolt Would you like to turn that into an answer? I already talked about game recommendation questions in my first sentence. My question was: does that situation apply to this one as well?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a duplicate of [Why are game recommendation questions off-topic?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6692), because I don't see why any of that reasoning wouldn't apply here. Card recommendations are the exception to the rule in my opinion.

Comment: Can you explain why card recommendations are a reasonable exception, to clarify why this *wouldn't* be?

Comment: @Cascabel That is explained in the answer to the question about card recommendations. Tomorrow someone is going to ask about some other kind of recommendation, and I'd rather point them to existing answers than pile on more opinions.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the answer should be a "No".

Game recommendations are IMO borderline relevant, but game design and questions related to game design is a completely different topic. Even the playtesting phase of game design is a different breed. It could probably make for a nice Exchange site of its own, though.

Comment: I am not sure that it would be able to generate enough traffic for there to be a board and card game development site.